# How to use enum as key in JSON object in java?

Tags: java, json, enums

I want to use enum as key in following JSON object. Here "For India" is the enum country.

```
{ "messages": {
            "For India": [
              {
                "title": "",
                "description": ""
              },
              {
                "title": "",
                "description": ""
              }
            ]
          }
}
```

I have created a view for the above JSON object. I am not able to use enum Country in following Views. Kindly help me on that.

```
@Data
public class Country {

List<CountryView> messages; // for key "messages"

}


@Data
public class CountryView {

String title;

String description;

}
```

Enum

```
enum Country{

    FOR_INDIA("For India");

    private String country;

    private Country(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry() {

        return this.country;

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `messages` key needs to hold a `Map<Country, List<CountryView>>` as a value

Comment: Which `JSON` library do you use? `Gson`, `Jackson`, other?